# force:lightningQuickAction . Will implementing this open the component as modalpop up directly?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute, modal, lightning-quickaction

I want to open a component as modal up from another custom  of another component.If my child component has  force:lightningQuickAction ,should that open directly as modal pop up without writing the code like slds_modal..etc..
or is  force:lightningQuickAction only for making the component available in quick action drop down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `force:LightningQuickAction` interface only allows the component to be used as a quick action - it doesn't automatically handle loading it in a modal. It will load in a modal if it's used as a quick action, but if it's used outside of that context then you'll need to handle creating the modal to load your component into.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification !!